# How to treat an error inside the try using only one catch?

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, nedb

I'm using `try-catch` to handle with the errors of my code.
Even reading and searching a lot, I'm still with some doubts.

In the piece of code bellow, I'd like to deal with any error that occurs inside the `try block`, but it captures an error only if it occurs in `db.find` line.
If the error occurs inside of `db.find` function, I mean, in the `if or else` code, this error is not captured by the `catch`.

```
routes.get('/app/:id', (req, res) => {
    var downloadUrl = http://url;
    try {
        db.find({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, subscriber) {            
            if (!subscriber.length) {
                res.render('info', { url: consts.baseUrl, message: consts.USERNOTFOUND });
            } else {
                res.render("app", { downloadUrl: downloadUrl });
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        logger.error(`${e.status || 500} - ${e.message} - /app`);
    }
});
```

To capture an error in `if else block` (lets suppose that the `var subscriber` doesnt exists) I need to put another `try catch` like that:

```
routes.get('/app/:id', (req, res) => {
    var downloadUrl = consts.baseUrl + 'downloadapk/' + req.params.id;
    try {
        db.find({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, subscriber) {            
            try{
                if (!suabscriber.length) {
                    res.render('info', { url: consts.baseUrl, message: consts.USERNOTFOUND });
                } else {
                    res.render("app", { downloadUrl: downloadUrl });
                }
            }catch(e){
                logger.error(`${e.status || 500} - ${e.message} - /app`);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        logger.error(`${e.status || 500} - ${e.message} - /app`);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure that use try-catch inside another is the best solution.
So how can I treat any error inside the try using only one catch?

Comment: That second inner catch is not needed your outer will catch also that inner error. it doesn't matter how nested your code is you can only use on try catch. The only exception is with promises but for those you have catch function that work the same.

Comment: Also this may be different if you `db.find` use some kind of async code, does error in inner callback function thrown outside of outter catch? Not sure this may happen if db is async code from indexedDB.

Comment: I can't tell from the NeDB documentation whether `.find()` returns a Promise (or can be made to do so).

Comment: @jcubicif If I remove the inside try-catch the error is not treated, maybe it is occurring due the nedb.

Comment: It may require a wrapper to use a Promise and `.catch()`; the "promisify" Node module would probably help.

Comment: You should check the error parameter and throw an error if it is set. As currently coded, you are catching errors unhandled by db.find() function

Comment: @KevinCoulibaly I didn't figured out how to do it, sorry. Is there any example?